# Событие onclick. Передача B js-функцию внутри класса.

Tags: javascript, html, функции

Событие onclick -

```
 <button id="button-send" onclick="SendToOrderPhp.send()" class="button-on-form">Send</button>
```

Хочу передать в функцию внутри класса. 
И тут вопрос - функция статическая - если попытаюсь вызвать функцию, конструктор класса ведь не выполнит работу?

Как быть в таком случае?
Спасибо.

Сам код:

```
class SendToOrderPhp{
private let name_;
private let email_;
constructor(let name, let email){
this.name=name;
this.email=email;
}
static function send(){
fetch('/php/order.php',{
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name_,
        email: email_
    })
});
}
}
SendToOrderPhp(GetInputsFromHtml.getName, GetInputsFromHtml.getEmail);
SendToOrderPhp.send();
```

Comment: Статические методы класса не могут использовать напрямую поля класса. _"Как быть?"_ - передавать в статический метод либо экземпляр класса, либо сами значения `name` и `email`.

Comment: А про передачу экземпляра - это выход! Большое спасибо! 
Напишите как ответ, что бы я мог отметить)

Comment: На здоровье. Ответ добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статические методы класса не могут использовать напрямую поля класса.

*"Как быть?"*:

- можно передавать в статический метод экземпляр класса
- можно передавать в него сами значения `name` и `email`
- можно метод сделать нестатическим

В первом и третьем случаях где-то должен храниться экземпляр класса, во втором - сами значения.